# Exposed filters: None vs. All results

Tags: drupal, field, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a view which has some exposed fields. When the view comes up the first time, all of the exposed fields are set up to not restrict the output in any way. So the view shows all of the records matching the criteria. I would like to make it so that, in that situation, none of the records show up. Or, even better, let the user choose whether some or no results show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a well known problem, you will find solution here :
http://drupal.org/node/358546

PS: This feature is available in views 3.